# Why am I getting run time error 91 with my code?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, runtime-error

When I try to run this code I get the error "Run-time error '91': object variable or with block variable not set" I'm new to VBA so I don't quite know what the issue is. I believe it has to do with the 'Dim currentrow as string' line, because I know I have to declare the variable, but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()

Dim currentrow As String

currentrow = Range("A:A").Find(DatabaseEntry.textbox1.Value).Row

 If Me.textbox1.Value = "" Then
 Msgbox "Run number cannot be blank", vbExclamation, "No"
 Exit Sub
 End If

 answer = Msgbox("Are you sure you want to update the record?", vbYesNo 
 + vbQuestion, "UpdateRecord")
 If answer = vbYes Then

 Cells(currentrow, 1) = textbox1.Value
 Cells(currentrow, 2) = textbox2.Value

 End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: What is `DatabaseEntry`? Also, `currentrow` should be a `Long`, not a `String`.

Comment: `DatabaseEntry` is the name of the spreadsheet

Comment: The actual sheet object name is `DatabaseEntry`, or just the name of the sheet? Because that would need to be written as `Worksheets("DatabaseEntry")` if you didn't change the object name in the editor.

Comment: Sorry-I misspoke. `DatabaseEntry` is the name of the userform..

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you perform a find:

- specify any other arguments which would impact the result, in addition to the value to be found
- check that you actually got a match *before* trying to access (eg) the Row

Like this:

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()

    Dim f As Range, v

    v = Trim(Me.textbox1.Value)
    
    If Len(v) = 0 Then
         Msgbox "Run number cannot be blank", vbExclamation, "No"
         Exit Sub
    End If

     Set f = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=v, _
                                          lookat:=xlWhole)
     If Not f Is Nothing Then
         if Msgbox("Are you sure you want to update the record?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "UpdateRecord") = vbYes Then
     
    
              With f.EntireRow
                  .Cells(1) = v  'really no need for this
                  .Cells(2) = textbox2.Value
              End With
          End If
     Else
         Msgbox "not found - '" & v & "'"
     End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am getting the 'not found' message though, not sure what the issue is there

Comment: If your data is numeric you may need to convert your search value to (eg) a Long since by default it's going to be a string.

Comment: ...if that doesn't work then maybe post some examples of what's in ColA